# Tags for panko and breading

Tags: discussion

I added a couple of questions about panko (which is a type of breading), and breading in general (which is a cooking technique that is usually discussed with battering). One of the mods suggested the `breadcrumb` tag, which doesn't really capture what I want (and isn't something I thought of).

Should we add additional tags to cover this broad cooking technique(s)? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2):

I added panko as a synonym for breadcrumbs already, because that's what it is. You can certainly bread things with panko, the same way you can with breadcrumbs. But panko itself is breadcrumbs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_crumbs

As for a [breading](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breading)... if someone thinks the tag is necessary, they can add it to their question (or edit it onto yours) and it'll stick around if it keeps getting used. I'm not sure yours really needs it, but if someone disagrees, they're welcome to add it.

Comment: Can you bread without breadcrumbs? I think that if there's no breadcrumbs, it's technically a batter; so a "breading" tag seems redundant.

Comment: @Aaronut Breading with cornflakes, and so on? I'm sure we could justify it, but I'm not sure how much it'd really help.